# Project with "aws" folder and s3*.py files?

Tags: python

These are some pics about the project structure from previous developers.

[image]

[image]

I can't figure out either which framework was used or how to run a project with that structure. Any ideas? Some kind of Python framework?

Comment: Can't you ask the previous developers?

Comment: to be honest im a mobile developer... my boss came today and said :"run this".

Answer (score 1):

The .py file are Python files and S3 and AWS (Amazon Web Services) references seems to be Amazon S3 service integration files.

Comment: any idea how to run this website?

Answer (score 0):

To my mind, you should `cd` to the `server` directory and run `python app.py`. *Maybe* this is the main file of the project. You should first download python from [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/).